# Correct way to type generic of DatePickerProps from DatePicker from mui-x

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, mui-x-date-picker

I have the following component and had set Localization like the following

```
function CustomDatePicker(props: DatePickerProps<unknown> & React.RefAttributes<HTMLDivElement>) {
  return (
    <StyledDatePicker
      disableHighlightToday
      format={DEFAULT_DATE_FORMAT}
      slots={{
        openPickerIcon: IconCalendar,
      }}
      {...props}
    />
  );
}
```

`LocalizationProvider` using AdapterDateFns

```
<LocalizationProvider
      dateAdapter={AdapterDateFns}
      adapterLocale={en}
> ....
```

I have it taking in props, what should i set the generic of `DatePickerProps<??>`

Having the generic set to `unknown`seem to work for now, but `onChange`'s`value` is typed as `unknown`.

```
<CustomDatePicker
  onChange={(value) => { //typeof value === unknown
....
```

now i have to type assert the value when using on a callback

```
onChange={value => onChangeDate(value as Date | null)}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Generic seems to be what your adapter returns, in my case built in `Date` because I am using date-fns adapters.
So if your using moment/dayjs, you set the generic as the corresponding object type.

Setting the generic will type the `onChange` and `value` props as a result